# Removing emoji/image hexcodes from twitter data

Tags: python, twitter, data-cleaning

I've downloaded a set of tweets as a csv file. I'm doing my EDA, but there are hexcodes in the data for emojis, and/or image links. How can I remove them across the entire dataset?

Below is what I did to replace the apostrophe hex code with an actual apostrophe, but that won't work because the emoji codes are different and I want to remove not replace them. The df is new_tweets, and just has the index and the text column. Each row in the text column is a tweet. Some examples(url shorteners don't pass thru S.O.'s spam filter so read it as such) : 
"'gratitude and happiness best describe what my wife means to me. I'm deeply grateful and purely happy \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'"

"'set in Goudy font, from Chicago *url shortener*'"

Any ideas on how to remove the emojis (first example) or links (second example) from all the tweets in my dataframe?

```
new_tweets['text'] = new_tweets['text'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('\\xe2\\x80\\x99',"'"))
```

Comment: I'd recommend using regular expressions to match the specific hex codes or URLs you'd like to remove. Then use `replace()` to remove them.

Comment: Try `tweet_text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`